# Only seeing ONE of two external HD's plugged into Apple Airport Extreme

Tags: wifi, airport, network, external-disk

Here is the scenario:

I have TWO External TB drives.
They are both plugged into a Powered USB Hub.
That Powered USB Hub is plugged into the back of my Airport Extreme.
I can only see one.
They have both been formatted with OS Extended (journaled).
Each are visible if only ONE is plugged in (i.e.  TB_A can be seen if just TB_A is plugged in, and TB_B can be seen if TB_B is the only one plugged in)

Does anyone have any ideas?  So frustrated because it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a similar problem using two flash drives, same size, same manufacturer. For whatever reason, the hub doesn't differentiate between the two. Try right-clicking on the drive that you can see and renaming it from "manufacturer xxxxx" or whatever it's called to something unique like "external drive A". Then shut down the entire setup (Mac, hub, Airport in that order) and restart everything (Airport, hub, Mac). That may help.

Comment: Update to my question. . . I had already changed the name of the drives, I did what you said about shutting down the entire setup in the order that you suggested, and then back on in the reverse order and VOILA!  It worked.  Thank you so much. . you were the only one on many forums to suggest this, and in turn , give me the solution.  I truly appreciate it!

Comment: @Michael if the solution works for you, click the green checkbox to the left of the answer to mark it as "accepted". This earns reputation for both you and the answerer, and lets future readers with the same problem know that this is the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is the hub itself. Often times the hubs can introduce problems with using all devices Plugged in to them. I used to use a passive hub with my airport extreme. Try picking up a cheap passive hub, or use your hub passively and see if that helps. Unless your devices are powered by the USB port, I don't think the active hub is necessary.

Comment: I'd love to know for certain if the apple airport CAN do it.  If it can, how do I make a hub "passive" ?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I don't think the AirPort Extreme will support more than one drive connected at a time.
I had wanted to do something similar to this a while back for backup purposes and I'm sure that I read it wouldn't work which is why I didn't proceed with it.

Comment: I currently have three connected and working, so this is not correct.